# Return value to csh script using Perl

Tags: perl, return, csh

I wrote a Perl script, and it returned 1 or 0 depending on whether it fails/succeeds. I had a .csh shell script that reads the return value.

The .csh command is this:

```
> setenv CHECKER `perl $BIN_DIR/sgRevisionChecker.pl`
if($CHECKER) then
    do stuff
else
    echo 'Successful Run'
exit
endif
```

However, the Perl script won't pass the correct value even when in the Perl script I say "exit 1" or "exit 0".

However, if within the Perl script I do this:

```
print "1";
exit 1;
```

Then my shell script gets the value. It seems to get the value if I print it, but I don't think this is robust, and I want to do it the right way. I have tried other solutions, but printing seems to be the only fix.

What is the correct way to return a value from Perl to a .csh script?

Comment: Well, in bash, `RETURN=$( some_script.pl )` would set $RETURN to whatever the script printed. The proper thing to do would be `some_script.pl; RETURN=$?`

Comment: A quick google: http://bima.astro.umd.edu/checker/node22.html You want the $status variable.

Comment: I am not using bash. That doesn't work. I am in tcsh I believe.

Comment: Type this in: "ps -p $$" (without quotes) to get the shell that you are using

Comment: @CliffordMaxwell Yes, I was just trying to give you an idea with my original comment. I assumed that it was similar in csh.

Answer (score 0):

```
$BIN_DIR/sgRevisionChecker.pl
if($status) then
    # do stuff
else
    echo 'Successful Run'
    exit
endif
```

I just tried this with:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash 

exit 1

$ cat c.sh 
#!/bin/tcsh

./test.sh
if($status) then
    echo 'Fail'
else
    echo 'Successful Run'
endif

$ ./c.sh
Fail
```

Or even shorter :

```
> perl -e 'exit 1'
> echo $status
1
```

Comment: @CliffordMaxwell Works for me on tcsh.